# Spring-boot applicationDatasource.xml not reading from external properties

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, spring-boot

I'm trying to read the datasoruce JNDI from external properties but apparently it cannot read it.

I've tried this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="clarifyDS" jndi-name="${bd.clarify.jndi}"
        lookup-on-startup="false" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

But it throws the following error.

`SERVER: AdminServer [ERROR] [08-07-2019 14:16:18.088] (ClarifyDaoImpl.java:120) - [ obtenerColasAsoc idTx= ] - [obtenerColasAsoc]JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup '${bd.clarify.jndi}' didn't find subcontext '${bd'. Resolved ''; remaining name '${bd/clarify/jndi}'-org.springframework.jndi.JndiLookupFailureException: JndiObjectTargetSource failed to obtain new target object; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup '${bd.clarify.jndi}' didn't find subcontext '${bd'. Resolved ''; remaining name '${bd/clarify/jndi}'`

I only need the name of the datasource since this is configurated on a weblogic server. No need for user or password.

Here are the complete files

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans          
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop          
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd          
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context          
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd        
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="pe.com.claro.postventa.consultacolas" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:${file.properties}ConsultaColas/.properties" />

    <import resource="applicationDatasource.xml" />

</beans>
```

applicationDatasoruce.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="clarifyDS" jndi-name="${bd.clarify.jndi}"
        lookup-on-startup="false" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

</beans>
```

Here is my Java class.

```
@Repository
public class ClarifyDaoImpl implements ClarifyDao{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClarifyDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "clarifyDS")
    private DataSource clarifyDS;

    @Autowired
    Propiedades propiedades;

    private Utilitarios utilitarios = new Utilitarios();

    @Override
    public ObtenerColasAsocResponseBean obtenerColasAsoc(String mensajeTransaccion, ObtenerColasAsocRequestBean request)
            throws DBException {

        //Do something
    }

}
```

Maybe I'm not using the correct syntax for reading the property file

Btw I'm not sure if this is the best way of setting the conexion to a database if someone know a better way I'd be glad to hear.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are using spring-boot have you considered using spring-data-jpa for configuring your database ?

Comment: I'm only executing store procedures that's why I had not considered it. btw haven't found any useful example.